# How memory store signed and unsigned char

Tags: c, assembly, char, unsigned, signed

Just started to learn C, and i feel little bit confused.

I have some questions:

1. If i have the following code:

```
signed  char x = 56;
// ‭In the RAM, I will see 00111000‬ yes/no?

signed char z = -56;
// In the RAM, I will see 11001000 yes/no?

unsigned char y = 200;
// ‭In the RAM, I will see 11001000‬ yes/no?
```

2. I have the following code:

```
if (z<0){
   printf("0 is bigger then z ");
}
```

After compiling, how the assembly instructions know if z is -56 and not 200?(there is a special ASM instructions for signed and unsigned?).

As i mentioned in question number 1, the value of z and y is 11001000, and there is not any indicate to know if its signed or unsigned.

Apologize if i didn't find the right way to ask my question, hope you understand me
Thanks

Comment: (1) Yes, (2) The compiler knows the types of the variables and will generate the assembly language to handle them that way.

Comment: I would recommend choosing the posted answer that best answers your question and "accept" it (click the Accept check) if you find it satisfactory.

Answer (score 5):

Numbers are stored in binary. Negative numbers are usually stored as two's complement form, but C language allows different representations. So this one:

```
signed char z = -56;
// In the RAM, I will see 11001000 yes/no?
```

usually yes, but may be not on some exotic platforms.

Second question is too implementation specific. For example comparison against zero on x86 may be performed as self-comparison, and `flags` register would be affected, for unsigned comparison sign flag (`SF`) is ignored.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler will generate the appropriate instructions for the signed and unsigned cases. I think it might better to see an example. The following code

```
void foobar();

void foo(unsigned char a)
{
    if (a < 10)
        foobar();
}

void bar(char a)
{
    if (a < 10)
        foobar();
}
```

Will translate to this MIPS code with GCC 5.4 using `-O3` flag.

```
foo:
        andi    $4,$4,0x00ff
        sltu    $4,$4,10
        bne     $4,$0,$L4
        nop

        j       $31
        nop

$L4:
        j       foobar
        nop

bar:
        sll     $4,$4,24
        sra     $4,$4,24
        slt     $4,$4,10
        bne     $4,$0,$L7
        nop

        j       $31
        nop

$L7:
        j       foobar
        nop
```

This is the interesting part of the `foo` function (which use `unsigned char` type)

```
foo:
        andi    $4,$4,0x00ff
        sltu    $4,$4,10
```

As you can see `sltu` command used which is the unsinged version of `slt`. (You don't really have to know what it does)

While if we looking at the function `bar` relevants part

```
bar:
        sll     $4,$4,24
        sra     $4,$4,24
        slt     $4,$4,10
```

You can see that `slt` used which will treat its register operand as signed. The `sll` and `sra` pair doing sign extension since here the operands `a` was signed so its needed, while in unsigned case its not.

So you could see that different instructions generated with respect to the signdess of the operands.

Comment: Note that some ABIs have `char` = `unsigned char`, so it would be maybe better to write your signed example as `signed char`.  Clearly for the ABI you picked (MIPS), `char` = `signed char` of course, but if someone wanted to try the same thing on ARM they'd get the same code for both functions.

Comment: It's somewhat misleading to say that extension isn't needed in the unsigned case.  *sign* extension isn't needed, but `andi  $4,$4,0x00ff` is doing *zero*-extension from `unsigned char` to `int`.  (Or more specifically, to the register width / operand size for `slt`, because MIPS doesn't have instructions that only look at the low 8 bits of a reg.)  I thought MIPS calling conventions normally passed/returned narrow args sign-extended to 32-bit, but apparently GCC isn't assuming that.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler will generate different instructions depending on whether it is an unsigned or signed type. And that is what tells the processor which way to treat it. So yes there are seperate instructions for signed and unsigned. With Intel processors, there are also seperate instructions depending on the width (char, short, int)

Comment: @ALevy: Note that *most* instructions are the same for signed 2's complement or plain binary unsigned.  Like `add eax, 1` is the same for both.  Only compares, right shift, and division are different.  e.g. signed compares look at OF != SF for less than vs. greater than.  http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt describes how ALUs calculate both unsigned carry-out and signed overflow results for the same addition.  It's up to software which flags it looks at.

Answer (score 1):

> there is a special ASM instructions for signed and unsigned?

Yes, hardware generally has machine code instructions (or instruction sequences) that can

- sign extend a byte to word size
- zero extend a byte to word size
- compare signed quantities for the various relations <, <=, >, >=
- compare unsigned quantities for the various relations <, <=, >, >=

> how the assembly instructions know if z is -56 and not 200?

In high level languages we associate a type with a variable.  From then on the compiler knows the default way to interpret code that uses the variable.  (We can override or change that default interpretation using a cast at usages of the variable.)

In machine code, there are only bytes, either in memory or in CPU registers.  So, it is not how it is stored that matter (for signed vs. unsigned), but what instructions are used to access the storage.  The compiler will use the right set of machine code instructions every time the variable is accessed.

While we store lots of things in memory, the processor has no concept of variable declarations.  The processor only sees machine code instructions, and interprets all data types through the eyes of the instruction it is being told to execute.

As an assembly programmer, it is your job to apply the proper instructions (here signed vs. unsigned) to the same variable each time it is used.  Using a byte as a signed variable and later as an unsigned variable, is a logic bug that is easy to do in assembly language.

Some assemblers will help if you use the wrong size to access a variable, but none that I know help if you use the proper size but incorrect signed-ness.

Answer (score 0):

Computers do not know nor care about such things.  Unsigned and signed is only relevant to the programmer.  The value 0xFF can at the same time be -1, 255 or an address or a portion of an address. Part of a floating point number and so on.  The computer does not care.  HOW the programmer conveys their interpretation of the bits is through the program.  Understanding that addition and subtraction also do not care about signed vs unsigned because it is the same logic, but other instructions like multiplies where the result is larger than the inputs or divide where the result is smaller than the inputs then there are unsigned and signed versions of the instructions or your processor may only have one and you have to synthesize the other (or none and you have to synthesize both).

```
int fun0 ( void )
{
    return(5);
}
unsigned int fun1 ( void )
{
    return(5);
}
00000000 <fun0>:
   0:   e3a00005    mov r0, #5
   4:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000008 <fun1>:
   8:   e3a00005    mov r0, #5
   c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

no special bits nor nomenclature...bits is bits.

The compiler driven by the users indication of signed vs unsigned in the high level language drive instructions and data values that cause the alu to output flags that indicate greater than, less than, and equal through single flags or combinations, then a conditional branch can be taken based on the flag.  Often but not always the compiler will generate the opposite if z < 0 then do something the compiler will say if z >= 0 then jump over the something.